How to trigger initialization of InternalSecurityPermissions.AppPathDiscovery in .NET Web API when running MSTest unit tests?
I am trying to use the MSTest testing framework to write unit tests for an ASP.NET Web API that uses the Oracle ManagedDataAccess library to connect to our database. The Oracle library is trying to read this property from the HttpRuntime class:
/// <summary>Gets the physical drive path of the application directory for the application hosted in the current application domain.</summary>
/// <returns>The physical drive path of the application directory for the application hosted in the current application domain.</returns>
public static string AppDomainAppPath
{
    get
    {
        InternalSecurityPermissions.AppPathDiscovery.Demand();
        return AppDomainAppPathInternal;
    }
}

However, when running unit tests the AppPathDiscovery object is null. In my unit tests I am initializing the HTTP context like this:
//pretend like this controller was called from a web request
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/utilScrape/scrapeData");
request.SetConfiguration(config);
var descriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(config, "UtilScrapeController", typeof(UtilScrapeController));
var actionDescriptor = new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(descriptor, typeof(UtilScrapeController).GetMethod("Post"));
var actionContext = new HttpActionContext
{
    ActionDescriptor = actionDescriptor
};
var mockRequestContext = new Mock<HttpRequestContext>();
controller.RequestContext = mockRequestContext.Object;
controller.ActionContext = actionContext;
controller.Request = request;

//authorize ourselves 
var identity = new GenericIdentity("ANTHONY");
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
var currentContext =  new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost", ""),
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
);
HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;


// Attach the ActionDescriptor to the Request.Properties
request.Properties["MS_HttpActionDescriptor"] = actionDescriptor;

That successfully initializes the controller's Request context, but I cannot figure out how to make AppPathDiscovery initialize itself. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory provides the same value, but I can't edit the Oracle library to make it use that.
I tried to force initialization like this:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\source\\Workspaces\\CONFIG\\SolutionsAPI.config");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase = "/";

It did not make a difference.
